# Count how many times a specific value appears in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an html table that contains a list of names within sentences, which are inside `<td>` elements (i.e. `<td>Mike (Jeremy's father) used to play piano</td>` or `<td>The only one who speaks french is Desmond, but Mike speaks very well spanish</td>`). I would like to count how many times a specific name appears within the **entire** table. I need this to be done through javascript/jquery, and not via php.
Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: and if the text is about Mr. Bob who was found bobbing in the water in the midst of the remains of his collection of fishing bobbers?

Comment: @MarcB Then trow an [`URIError`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.6.6).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
var nbMikeInTheTable = (' '+$('table').text()+' ').split('Mike').length-1;
```

*(the added ' ' are for the compatibility with the buggy implementation of split on IE)*

Or, if you want to be sure it's the entire word and it's not cut by HTML

```
 var nbMikeInTheTable = $('table').html().split(/\W+/).filter(
     function(v){return v=="Mike"}
 ).length;
```

If you want to guard against end of words and end of cells *and be sure it's not part of an attribute of a `td`*, it's a little more complex :

```
var nbTimesMikeIsInTheTable = $('table td').map(function(){
    return $(this).text().split(/\W+/).filter(function(v){return v=="Mike"}).length
}).toArray().reduce(function(p,v){return p+v});
```

*This isn't elegant but is probably not needed ;)*

[Demonstration (open the console)](http://jsfiddle.net/KVYt7/)

Comment: What if one cell ends with `'Mi'`, and the next cell starts with `'ke'`?

Comment: Regarding your update, that will also catch occurrences within attribute names/values. (I'm playing devil's advocate here `:)`)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I made a third version for this (not probable) risk. I'm sure it's possible to shorten it a little but it's probably not worth the pain...

Comment: I did manage to shorten it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/KVYt7/1/ `$.map()` flattens arrays, so I just mapped TDs to word-arrays, which produced one big array of words. Then I just applied the filter function.

Comment: ...and with a little bit of functional programming, we get a big improvement in readability: http://jsfiddle.net/KVYt7/2/ `var n = $.map( cellsArray, toWordsArray ).filter( byValue( 'Mike' ) ).length;`.